# Appropriate visa for visiting student research in Australia

Tags: indian-citizens, australia

I have been offered to join a University in Australia as a visiting student research on a project for 3-6 months (depends on the visa duration).

I am currently enrolled as a

- Student in the University in New Zealand
- with Indian Passport and
- staying in India from last 1 month.

What kind of visa do I need for this? I am a bit confused between

- Training and Research visa subclass 402 (Occupational Trainee Stream) and
- Temporary Work visa (Short stay activity) subclass-400.

Can someone please suggest anything regarding this?

Comment: Would this belong into Expatriates?

Comment: @o.m. No, I am an Indian and currently in India. But was in New Zealand from July 2014 - July2015.

Comment: generally, the university you are visiting can help with this. That's my experience assisting a visiting scholar getting a visa to elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's some information on [this Department of Immigration and Border Protection](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Stud) page, but essentially, you will most likely need a:

- Higher Education Sector Visa (subclass 573)
- Postgraduate Research Sector Visa (subclass 574)

The subclass 400 and 402 visas are related to employment and on-the-job training, and so probably aren't going to work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response @jimsug .  the university is not informing about the exact visa type, however they are suggesting 402 visa. I found a document online (https://www.universitiesaustralia.edu.au/ArticleDocuments/184/Academic%20Scenario%20Guidance%20Sheet.pdf.aspx) that suggested that 400 can be an option if the research project is not part of the course, which is not in my case. Your views in this regard, please?

Comment: Are you going to be doing paid work, and the research is part of the training for it? If not, then the 402 - Research Stream may be more suitable.

Comment: They are not paying a salary, However they will be paying a subsistence allowance for the duration of the placement to assist with living expenses related to the visit.